# Mass email contacts from organization wide address

Tags: massemailmessage

I want to send a mass email to all my contacts (using the mass email wizard) but would like to have the "from" address be my organization wide address (like info@aaaa.com).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Every week I come across real head-scratchers like this in SFDC, in general I like working on the platform, but stuff like this seems so....silly

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Organization wide email address by going to: Your Name | Setup | Administration Setup | Email Administration | Organization-Wide Addresses.

Here you can add addresses and assign them to roles/profiles. When sending an email you will then have the option to select which "from" profile you would like to select.

Comment: Upvoted as this the right way to go.

Comment: Org Wide Addresses are a great solution, but are incompatible with mass-emailing (even today), so this doesn't answer the original question unfortunately, @TheMikeyBoosh response is more accurate

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Launa is incorrect, you cannot use an "Organization wide email address" in conjunction with Mass Mail.

Its possible to assign the same email address to multiple users though...

Answer (score 0):

You could assign that email address to a user.

Comment: and change his name as well...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a handy way to circumvent this limitation and send mass email from an organisation wide email address. This doesn't use the MassEmailMessage class, it uses the ListEmail and ListEmailIndividualRecipient tables directly. It derives from the Ojbect Reference Manual for the ListEmail object where under the field "Status" it says "Read-only except when list email is in draft state. Changing the status to Scheduled causes the list email to be sent. Valid values: Draft, Scheduled, Sent, Limit Error, Cancelled".

This got me thinking so I tried the following code.

ListEmail LE = New ListEmail(); // Create a New List Email

LE.HtmlBody = HtmlValue; // HtmlValue is the HTML email body, which can be pulled from a template

LE.Status='Draft'; // Important. Create as a draft

LE.Subject=Subject; // Set the Subject

LE.TextBody=Body; // Body is the text value of the email body

LE.Name=Subject; // Probably can use what you want here

LE.FromAddress=EmailAddress; // The verified organisation wide email address

LE.FromName=DisplayName; // Display name of the org wide email address

Insert LE; // Insert as we need the ID below

List  LEIRs = New List (); // New list of recipients

For ( ID I : ListContactIDs ) // ListContactIDs - previously created list of contact ID to receive the email

```
{

LEIRs.Add( New ListEmailIndividualRecipient(ListEmailId = LE.ID,RecipientId = I) ); // Add contact to list

}
```

Insert LEIRs; // Insert recipient list

LE.Status='Scheduled'; // Set List email status to 'Scheduled' as per documentation

Update LE; // Update. This causes the List Email to be sent to all recipients. "Status" changes to Sent

The email are all sent out just as if they were list emails / mass emails.